# How were “bratrъ/bratъ” and “sestra” formed in PSl?

Tags: etymology, proto-indo-european, slavic-languages

The PIE r-stem words seem to have lost the final -r in PSl: OCS mati, dъšti, and how some words which had -r (and -l) in final position preserve this consonant in the middle of words in slavic?

Comment: i assume you do know that many Slavic languages have brat instead of bratr...  Which sound change or law do you believe removed the final liquids? Or do you propose such law? You write "seem to have lost" does it seem to you or do you have some citation of some scholarly resource?

Comment: By whom? Please provide a citation. In general, Slavic lost many final consonants due to the law of open syllables. However, here we have an open syllable thanks to the final yer.

Comment: It is commonly accepted that PSl lost all final consonants (-r, -t, -d, -s) at different stages of development of PSl. Many scholars explain the cause of this language phenomenon as “law of rising sonority “, although I highly doubt that if all the final consonants dropped on this account.

Comment: OK, that is the broader version that includes the law of the open syllables. Does “bratrъ" violate this law? I do not think so. Depending on what the preceding form was it may or may not be the most-straightforward expected result, but I do not think the law is violated.

Comment: Btw., Shevelov in “A prehistory of Slavic” proposed a new point of view that final consonants dropped due to other reasons instead of “law of rising sonority (which leads to law of open syllables)”.

Comment: I didn’t say that this law was violated by words like “bratrъ” and “sestra”. Apparently there was something added after the r-stem and I-stem words so that the -r and -l were preserved in the middle of the words. What I am curious about is the way these words are formed.

Comment: Kortland apparently discusses it on page 127 of https://books.google.cz/books?hl=cs&lr=&id=Lvx5DwAAQBAJ&oi=fnd&pg=PP3&dq=kortland+selected+writings+on+slavic&ots=eC6S6ss8Ww&sig=3NFGK5MY0yeV2V9n_SQ9DI5WM60&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=and%20sestra%20restructuring&f=false  Unfortunately, I do not have access to that, our faculty library only has one books about phonemes by this author. I'd b interested in the answer myself.

Comment: Jutro is similar to sestra so might be of interest https://doi.org/10.1080/00806765.2019.1672096

Comment: I have the pdf version of this book. I’d be glad to share it with you.))

Comment: That's fine, I can manage to get it through the library if needed. However, if there is some answer to this queation in there, you can write an answer with the content.