# Are "brat" and "frater" cognates?

Tags: etymology, proto-indo-european, latin, slavic-languages, cognates

Both the Slavic *brat* (Брат) and the Latin *frater* mean **brother**.

Are they cognates?  Or is their phonetic "proximity" a red herring?

---

<sub>Related: [How were “bratrъ/bratъ” and “sestra” formed in PSl?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/40311/13357)</sub>

Comment: Yes, they are: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/frater#Latin and https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82#Russian

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it can be answered by a quick wiktionary lookup.

Comment: @jk-ReinstateMonica And how is one supposed to know that Wiktionary is credible when Wikipedia is obviously not?

Comment: You can always check the given sources in the entries. When claims are unsourced, this is a warning signal.

Comment: @jk-ReinstateMonica Yes, but I don't know which sources are credible either.  I would rather ask here, especially since people may post under their actual names and put their credibility at stake. I don't see many actual names in [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=брат&action=history).

Comment: No problem with that. I boldly edit tags when I feel that there are better ones than those chosen by the original poster.

Comment: @jk-ReinstateMonica I am wondering whether I should replace [tag:latin] with [tag:romance-languages].  Would you recommend that I do so? In Romanian, "frate"="brother".

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo There's no need. All Romance languages are derived from Latin. Keeping it with Latin is fine.

Comment: No wonder this site is dying a slow death when good questions like this are treated this way. Maybe we can get it so that questions only average 5 views in the future.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, *frater* and *Брат* are related.

They ultimately come from the Proto-Indo-European **bʰréh₂tēr*, from which indeed *brat/Брат* in various Slavic languages also is derived. You can see the descendants on [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Slavic/bratr%D1%8A). In Latin, the PIE initial bʰ- regularly yielded f-. Another example is the PIE **bʰer-*, which yields *bear* in English and *ferre* in Latin.

It's certainly good to question whether two words are "false cognates", as plenty of words in languages can look the same but come from entirely separate origins. In this case, though, the various words for "brother" in Proto-Indo-European languages is actually clear cut.

As far as Wiktionary goes, it is generally reliable, but you can always check a Latin etymological dictionary like [De Vaan's](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Etymological_Dictionary_of_Latin_and_the/ecZ1DwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=de+vaan+latin+etymology&printsec=frontcover) if you're unsure.

Comment: worth noting that whilst wiktionary is generally reliable (when it gives etymologies that is), it's citation requirements are pretty lax. For someone with enough background knowledge to distinguish plausible etymologies from folk that's good enough for quick checks, but for people without any background can be tricky

Comment: @Tristan Definitely a sound point. I've found that it has generally done a good job at removing their folk etymologies, but every once in a while some incorrect facts creep in.